# How can I clamp rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyLookAt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 offset;

    Transform chest;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        chest.LookAt(target.position);

        ClampRotation(chest.rotation, new Vector3(0, 60, 0));
        chest.rotation = chest.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(offset);
    }

    public static Quaternion ClampRotation(Quaternion q, Vector3 bounds)
    {
        q.x /= q.w;
        q.y /= q.w;
        q.z /= q.w;
        q.w = 1.0f;

        float angleX = 2.0f * Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan(q.x);
        angleX = Mathf.Clamp(angleX, -bounds.x, bounds.x);
        q.x = Mathf.Tan(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * angleX);

        float angleY = 2.0f * Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan(q.y);
        angleY = Mathf.Clamp(angleY, -bounds.y, bounds.y);
        q.y = Mathf.Tan(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * angleY);

        float angleZ = 2.0f * Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan(q.z);
        angleZ = Mathf.Clamp(angleZ, -bounds.z, bounds.z);
        q.z = Mathf.Tan(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * angleZ);

        return q.normalized;
    }
}
```

I tried to use the ClampRotation method but it does nothing. The player's head still can be rotated 360 degrees if the target is behind him. I want to limit the rotation to some human natural looking to the sides and maybe also to the up/down.

I tried this testing the Y (up/down)

```
Vector3 chestAngle = chest.eulerAngles;
        chestAngle.y = (chestAngle.y > 180) ? chestAngle.y - 360 : chestAngle.y;
        chestAngle.y = Mathf.Clamp(chestAngle.y, -50, 50);    
        chest.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(chestAngle);
```

but it's clamping the Z and not the Y. It's clamping the Left not the up/down.  I want to clamp up/down and left/right

Comment: mmmm, Try to use `Vector3.Dot` or `Vector3.Cross` to control a range and then enable the `LookAt`.

Comment: Your quaternion code is **totally incorrect in every possible way**.  That is **not even vaguely close** to how quats work mathematically.  Do not, ever, try to manipulate the math of quaternions!  All you do is use lookAt, it's that easy

Answer (score 0):

You're never assigning the clamped value to the rotation.

`chest.rotation = ClampRotation(chest.rotation, new Vector3(0, 60, 0));`

Answer (score 0):

Forget the `ClampRotation` Function and try the following code :

```
Vector3 chestAngle = chest.rotation.eulerAngles;
chestAngle.y = (chestAngle.y > 180) ? chestAngle.y - 360 : chestAngle.y;
chestAngle.y = Mathf.Clamp(chestAngle.y, -50 , 50);
chest.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(chestAngle);
```